# MFMailComposeViewController: Siri command to send

Tags: mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, siri

I am using MFMailComposeViewController to send an email within my iOS app. Is it possible to create a "Send" Siri command to actually send the email? Or does the user have to physically tap the send button? I'm guessing they do, for security reasons...